# Firebase Cloud Messaging with Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use the [newly released Firebase Messaging Nuget for Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/32.961.0-beta1)
Referring to [this sample](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/blob/v9.4.0/firebase-messaging/samples/FirebaseMessagingQuickstart/MainActivity.cs) which says:

> Make sure you've downloaded your own config (google-services.json file) file and added it to your app project with the 'GoogleServicesJson' build action.

I've downloaded the file & added it to the project, but can't fine the build action of type GoogleServiceJson, what am I missing?

Because of which I am getting a compilation issue at 
 if (GetString(Resource.String.google_app_id) == "YOUR-APP-ID") as the app is not able to find the resource string named google_app_id.

Could someone please help me understand what is missing? 
Thanks

Comment: was getting the same error yesterday - clean and rebuild then try - if not visible then restart VS

Comment: related Github issue: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/25

Comment: and if there is a parsing excpetion - make sure that google-services.json is encoded in "UTF-8 without BOM"

Answer (score 0):

After Adding google-service.json file to your project.
Select google-service.json file and go to the property of the file.
In the Properties pane, set the Build Action to GoogleServicesJson (if the GoogleServicesJson build action is not shown, save and close the Solution, then reopen it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtkTc.png)